# Confusion between exponential functions e.g. $10^x$ and $e^x$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, graphing-functions, exponentiation, radicals

Assume we we have the following exponential function: $10^x$
If we think about it across the x-axis in $0$ the height of the $y$ axis is $1$ and where $x = 1$ it is $10$.
Now if we split the $[0,1]$ to subintervals of $\frac{1}{1000}$ where the function grows we know

1. we need $1000$ such intervals to reach from $0$ to $1$
2. The function grows with the rate of $1 + \frac{2305}{1,000,000}$ since we know that  $(1 + \frac{2305}{1,000,000})^{1000} = 1.002305^{1000} \approx 10$. This is based on $\sqrt [1000]{10} = 1.00230523808$

Now if I simplify a bit what is mentioned in $2$ we get $1 + \frac{2305}{1,000,000}\approx 1 + \frac{2000}{1,000,000} = 1 + \frac{1}{500} = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$ so it is a form of $(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n$ which we know that for larger numbers of $n$ this equals $2.71828... = e$

But this is the $10^x$ function and when $n$ reaches $1000$ it should be equal $10$.
So where am I making a mistake here?

Comment: The paragraph beginning "now if I simplify a bit" involves two imprecise approximations, one explicitly labeled "$\approx$" and the other hidden behind the phrases "is a form of" and "for larger numbers." Try to make those approximations precise.

Comment: Well, $(1+1/500)^{500}\approx e,$ so $(1+1/500)^{1000}\approx e^2=7.3$ But those extra $300$ that you rounded off makes it bigger. $\frac{2305}{1000000}\approx \frac1{434},$ so $$(1+1/433)^{1000}\approx e^{1000/434}\approx e^{2.3}\approx 9.97$$

Comment: Basically, you need a more digits than you’d expect when doing exponentiation.

Comment: Just a quibble $1+1/500$ of course, is not of the form $(1+1/n)^n.$

Comment: For $k$ small, you’d expect: $$(1+k/1000000)^{1000}\approx e^{k/1000}.$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Being more accurate it is $1 + \frac{2305238}{1,000,000,000} = 1 + \frac{1152619}{500,000,000}$. So if I start rounding to simplify the fraction e.g. $1 + \frac{1152619}{500,000,000} \approx 1 + \frac{1000000}{500,000,000} = 1 + \frac{1}{500}$ the problems appear and this should be: $(1 + \frac{1}{500})^{1000} = (1 + \frac{1}{500})^{500 \cdot 2} = e^2$? So in general is it possible to write these in simpler form without introducing such problems?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: So $(1 + \frac{k}{1,000,000})^{1000} = (1 + \frac{k}{1,000}\cdot \frac{1}{1000})^{1000}$ and that equals $e^{\frac{k}{1000}}$. How do we get the last equality? I.e. $(1 + \frac{k}{1,000}\cdot \frac{1}{1000})^{1000} = e^{\frac{k}{1000}}$?

Comment: It’s only $\approx.$ This is because $$\left(1+\frac1{1000000/k}\right)^{1000000/k}\approx e.$$ Raise both sides by the power $k/1000$ And you get: $$\left(1+\frac k{1000000}\right)^{1000}\approx e^{k/1000}$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I understand what you mean. The manipulations  you showed in the last comment were not obvious to me. Do you have some reference of common type of such manipulations I could read about?

Comment: There is nothing magical going on here. $(1+1/m)^m\approx e$ and so $(1+1/m)^{m\alpha}\approx e^{\alpha}.$ Here, $m=1000000/k, \alpha=k/1000.$ The error in the estimate depends on how large $m$ is and how small $\alpha$ is.